# Как сделать последовательный вывод текста на экран с задержкой?

Tags: c++

Есть код

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main () {    
    cout << "Hi!\n";    
    cout << "My name Vladimir...";    
    system ("pause >> void");    
}
```

Как сделать так, что бы первая надпись появилась сразу, а вторая через 3 секунды?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
    cout << "Hi!" << endl;
    sleep(3);
    cout << "My name Vladimir..." << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Добавьте #include <Windows.h>, и будет вам счастье.

Comment: чё добавить? странно, gcc ругается на windows.h =\

А если без windows.h - то все работает

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Мой компилятьр - Dev C++, показывает на ошибку в строке - sleep(3);

Comment: Ну значит ковыряйте в сторону функции sleep для вашей платформы/компилятора.

Comment: Ничего добавлять не надо. Все и так работает. Проверено на Ubuntu с g++.

Comment: Спасибо, у меня заработало!

Comment: А на Виндовс? Sleep надо писать с большой буквы, а windows.h я подключаю в MS Visual Studio. Пусть автор укажет версию среды и ось!

Comment: Спасибо, очень помогли!!!!

Answer (score 1):

В windows.h(если не путаю) есть функия Sleep, принимающая в качестве аргументов кол-во миллисекунд. Т.е. Sleep(3000) сделает задержку в 3 секунды.

Comment: Ошибка в строке "sleep(3000);"

 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

 int main () {
  cout << "Hi!" << endl;
  sleep(3000);
  cout << "My name Vladimir..." << endl;
  return 0;
 }

Comment: @VladimirVi функцию Sleep нужно писать с заглавной буквы!

Answer (score 1):

[найдено](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672338/how-to-sleep-for-5-seconds-in-windowss-command-prompt-or-dos) на SO

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main () {    
    cout << "Hi!\n";
    system ("ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 3000 > nul");
    cout << "My name Vladimir..." << endl;    
    system ("pause");    
}
```

Comment: Обалдеть! 

Да, уж, если кто-то что-то написал на SO, так это истина в последней инстанции...

На самом деле, для переносимости всего-то навсего достаточно добавить код:

    #ifdef WIN32
    #include <windows.h>
    #define sleep(s) Sleep((s) * 1000)
    #endif

где-нибудь в начале программы.

Comment: @avp мне оригинальное решение проблемы понравилось. я б до такого никогда сам не додумался.